# Context menu strip item Disable in datagrid

Tags: c#, datagrid

Im using a Context Menu Strip in a datagrid and i'm trying to disable it's item on opening Event

```
miEditOrder.Enabled = dgwImage.RowCount > 1;
```

it works just if the Context Menus Strip is set to dgwImage but not if it is set to RowTempalte -> ContexMenuStrip,

thanx